# Crashlytics reports with Swift methods are hard to read

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

I recently discovered problems reading Crashlytics reports for crashes in Swift code.
In the picture below you can see what happend to the method names. **I've highlighted the interesting information in it:**

> **String+File.swift line 21**
>   $SSo7`UIImage`C7`mymodule`E4`load`_5`block`y10`Foundation`3`URL`V_yABSg_s5`Error`_pSgtctFZ080$S7`mymodule`23`ProfileViewController`C18`loadProfilePicture`yy10`Foundation`3`URL`VFySo7a6CSg_s5G9_pSgtcfU_AC0ijK0CSgXwz_XxTf1ncn_nTf4ndn_n

It is still usefull but harder to read and understand. Even though, sometimes it doesn't help at all.

I just wonder if there is a way to fix this.

Comment: `xcrun swift-demangle` most likely is what you are looking for

Comment: @Mindaugas is right. [here](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-15-swift-name-mangling.html) is more on Swift mangling

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. [This](https://fabric.io/blog/2016/09/08/how-crashlytics-symbolicates-1000-crashes-every-second/) may lead to something (the "Dealing with mangled symbols" section). It could be related to the migration they're making to the Firebase, because it has started a couple days ago for me, with an app already in production.

Comment: Mike from Firebase and Fabric here. Any symbolication changes are unrelated to any migrations. If you can contact support(at)fabric(dot)io with a link to the issues that you believe aren't being symbolicated correctly, please do so that we can dig in more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
It seems to be issue on Crashlytics side.
When you use latest (Crashlytics 3.11.1, Fabric 1.8.2) Frameworks then issue is visible.
Workaround is to use oldest version. For example: (Crashlytics 3.10.7, Fabric 1.7.11).
I reported this bug to Crashlytics support team.

Comment: Can you please confirm these versions (Crashlytics 3.10.7, Fabric 1.7.11) provides a solution for this problem? Recently I tried to use these versions and reports are still wrong mangled.